# Docker mounting /tmp/pulseaudio gives error

Tags: docker, ubuntu, audio, pulseaudio

I am trying to get sound out of my docker container. I am working on a Raspberry4 with Ubuntu 20.10.

When starting the container, I am using following lines to mount soundfile folders:

```
-v /tmp/pulseaudio.socket:/tmp/pulseaudio.socket
-v /tmp/pulseaudio.client.conf:/etc/pulse/client.conf
```

However, I am getting the following error:

> docker: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed:
> container_linux.go:367: starting container process caused:
> process_linux.go:495: container init caused: rootfs_linux.go:60:
> mounting "/tmp/pulseaudio.socket" to rootfs at
> "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/cde617898e2ee8e181a48cf84db8dbcdf5bfdf57e5760493f7c5fce1640b59d5/merged/tmp/pulseaudio.socket"
> caused: not a directory: unknown: Are you trying to mount a directory
> onto a file (or vice-versa)? Check if the specified host path exists
> and is the expected type.

How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are trying to mount something that not exist in the host to a file that exist in the docker.

In this case the behaviour is (see [here](https://docs.docker.com/storage/bind-mounts/#differences-between--v-and---mount-behavior)):

> If you use -v or --volume to bind-mount a file or directory that does not yet exist on the Docker host, -v will create the endpoint for you. It is always created as a directory.

So docker will create a folder in the host and try to mount it to a file in the container, and this is why you get error.

To fix it, you just need to check that the file is exist in the host, in your case `/tmp/pulseaudio.socket` and maybe also `/tmp/pulseaudio.client.conf`.

Please note that with `-v` the left path is for the host and the right is for the container.

```
-v /path/in/host:/path/in/container
```

Comment: /tmp/pulseaudio.socket folder exists in host. I am just trying to bind it to same path in docker, but it points to /var/lib/docker/overlay2/cde617898e2ee8e181a48cf84db8dbcdf5bfdf57e5760493f7c5fce1640b59d5/merged/tmp/pulseaudio.socket, which is why giving the error I guess.